# Crontab to another server

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ftp, putty, scp

I'm looking to transfer a file from my Ubuntu VPS via Crontab to my domain's FTP which is web hosted.

To provide context, there's a file on my VPS which I want to be made available on the internet, and it's constantly updating, so I want to push it from the VPS to the web server automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at creating a script that performs the FTP upload of your file from the VPS to your web server.

Then add a crontab entry to run that script at your required schedule.